# Airflow / Python - How to resume DAG flow based on external process

Tags: python, asynchronous, airflow

```
Using Airflow 1.8.0 and python 2.7
```

Having the following DAG (simplified):

```
(Phase 1)-->(Phase 2)
```

On phase 1 I'm triggering an async process that is time consuming and can run for up to 2 days, when the process ends it writes some payload on S3. On that period I want the DAG to wait and continue to phase 2 only when the S3 payload exists.

I thought of 2 solutions:

1. When phase 1 start pause the DAG using the [experimental REST API](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/rest-api-ref.html#get--api-experimental-dags--DAG_ID--dag_runs--string-execution_date--tasks--TASK_ID-) and resume once the process ends.
2. Wait using an operator that checks for the S3 payload every X minuets.

I can't use option 1 since my admin does not allow the experimental API usage and option 2 seems like a bad practice (checking every X minuets).

Are there any other options to solve my task?

Comment: What's the variance of the execution time of the async process? If it always takes around two days you could go for a TimeDeltaSensor and just start to check S3 after a certain time.

Comment: The execution time is unknown and ranges from several hours to couple of days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Option (2) is the "correct way", you may optimize it a bit:

[BaseSensorOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/base_sensor_operator/index.html#airflow.sensors.base_sensor_operator.BaseSensorOperator) supports `poke_interval`, so it should be usable for `S3KeySensor` to increase the time between tries.

> Poke_interval - Time in seconds that the job should wait in between
> each tries

Additionally, you could try to use `mode` and switch it to `reschedule`:

> mode: How the sensor operates.
> Options are: `{ poke | reschedule }`, default is `poke`.
> When set to `poke` the sensor is taking up a worker slot for its
> whole execution time and sleeps between pokes. Use this mode if the
> expected runtime of the sensor is short or if a short poke interval
> is required. Note that the sensor will hold onto a worker slot and
> a pool slot for the duration of the sensor's runtime in this mode.
> When set to `reschedule` the sensor task frees the worker slot when
> the criteria is not yet met and it's rescheduled at a later time. Use
> this mode if the time before the criteria is met is expected to be
> quite long. The poke interval should be more than one minute to
> prevent too much load on the scheduler.

Not sure about Airflow 1.8.0 - couldn't find the old documentation (I assume `poke_interval` is supported, but not `mode`).

Comment: Adding to that there is a [`S3KeySensor`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/sensors/s3_key_sensor.html) which can be used to sense the payload. Also if you are running workers in a shared environment where many other processes are running (and you  have to wait for max of 2 days) then `poke` mode is not recommended. Because the worker will be occupied by the task for poking which in turn consumes resources.